# Setting a specific Grain to have max n instances per Silo

Tags: c#, selenium, actor, orleans

I'm working on widening the capabilities of an already existing Selenium-based web application testing system. The system currently can only execute tests one at a time. I'd like to increase the system's throughput by adding some parallelism to test execution.

To that end I've been looking into different technologies and am interested in Microsoft's Orleans. However, after spending a day with Orlean's documentation I couldn't find if the technology supports the scenario where I need to run a specific scalable actor a maximum of n times on one computer.

In my case it would be the actor executing a test. Typically with Selenium, test execution requires creation of a WebDriver object which then opens and controls a web browser instance. Those web browsers all have to be open as separate processes not just new windows of same process. With no upper limit and lets say a cluster of 3 nodes and a test plan of 60 tests I'd have 20 web browsers opening simultaneously on each machine, which would likely lead to major decrease of performance or a complete crash. I'd expect the system to have an upper limit of 3 test executing actors per machine and store the rest of tests in a queue, running them only after another worker actor finishes it's test.

How would I go about implementing that with the Orleans technology?

Comment: Please, could the downvoting person leave a comment explaining what's wrong with the question? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Orleans, the right solution is NOT to muck around with MaxActiveThreads. You should not really be changing that, almost ever. Instead, you can either just have 9 regular grains total, use them by just having 9 different grain ids (0...8) and the system will spread them randomly across the 3 servers and when you send a new test request, just send it to a random grain out of those 9.

Alternatively, you have StatelessWorker grain, just one grain, but set its max activations (per server) to 3, and that way you will have exactly 3 activations per server (9 total) and the system will auto load balance.

http://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/StatelessWorker.html

There is no build in persistent queueing in Orleans. You will either have to queue on the client/sender side or send all 60 requests at once, and each grain can store the request in its internal in memory queue and start the next one when the work on the previous one has finished.

Comment: From what I've read about regular grains (regular meaning the not-a-StatelessWorker grains) you can have one activation per type within a cluster. In your regular grains solution I'd need to have 9 classes that differ in name but have identical implementation. Did I understand that right?

Also, StatelessWorkers are only created locally, so I cant have node A requesting the creation of StatelessWorker grains on node B.

Comment: You have one activation for a specific id globally. You have separate instances of the same grain type/class, identified by their id, distributed around the silos.

Comment: That makes sense, however how does it work? As I understand it I have no control on when and how grains are created, while that's actually exactly what I need: the ability to make sure certain grains are instantiated a set number of times on certain physical machines.

Comment: You do not have the exact full control with Orleans on where exactly the grains are instantiated. there are 2 options: 
1) regular grains instantiated on random server by Orleans (one grain instance per grain id).  This is what is called Virtual Actor. You can read more about it in Orleans documentation.
2) stateless workers are instantiated on each server, up to a configured limit per server (by default number of cores). Orleans will instantiate new stateless worker activations based on load. In your case up to 9 total, 3 max per server.

Answer (score 0):

Orleans will do most of your requirements out of the box.
It creates so many grains parallel as you have config in the silo (default is cpu cores see [MaxActiveThreads](https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/master/src/Orleans/Configuration/NodeConfiguration.cs#L116)). 
All other request will be queued by Orleans.

You can configure it in the Orleans config-file:

```
<Scheduler MaxActiveThreads="3"/>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details in your answer? For example how should the config you refer to look like? Code snippets are very welcome.

Comment: @Johnny did you manage to solve this problem? Did you manage to do it on the grain itself or on the host?

Comment: @DrSchizo I've gave up on Orleans and went with Akka.net instead. Managed to find a solution to my problem there.

Comment: How did Akka solve your problem? I'm deciding between the two at the moment but thought I'll give Orleans a try. I know Akka has pooling and routing capabilities is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes, I've solved this particular problem by creating a Akka.Net-managed actor pool that ensures there's exactly one instance of the worker actor on each machine that has a corresponding micro-service deployed on it.

Answer (score -2):

Your problem: You want to parallelize your test-execution.

The solution is to use the Selenium-hub and node. You don't need Orleans for that.

Comment: I wanted to give some context in my question so I've explained why I have this particular problem, however my question is precisely about Orleans. Selenium Grid actually isn't an option because we use wrapping methods over the Selenium ones and we also interact with non-web components in our tests.